# How many times International cricket match were won after needing 6 runs in 1 ball?

Tags: cricket, statistics

Over the years, there have been instances when batsmen have hit a six off the final ball of the match to win a game when they needed 4, 5 runs in a last ball.

Shivnarine Chanderpaul carried West Indies to a thrilling final-ball one-wicket win in the first one-day international in Port of Spain against Sri Lanka when they needed 6 run in last ball.

Is there any other international cricket match that were won on a last ball after needing 6 runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you found is the only time in international cricket that a team needed 6 off the last ball and won. I used statsguru and looked up teams that fielded first, won the match, and took the max number of balls. Then I just looked match-by-match (there weren't a whole lot) and looked if the team needed 6 off the last ball. Plenty of them hit a six, but the only team that needed a six was West Indies against Sri Lanka.

T20s:
http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?ballsmin1=120;ballsval1=balls;batting_fielding_first=2;class=3;filter=advanced;groupby=match;orderby=won;result=1;template=results;type=team

ODIs:
http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?ballsmax1=300;ballsmin1=300;ballsval1=balls;batting_fielding_first=2;class=2;filter=advanced;orderby=team_score;result=1;template=results;type=team;view=innings